# Is the equation $\sec (\pi/2)$= $\tan (\pi/2)$ true?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

While both $\sec (\pi/2)$ and $\tan (\pi/2)$ are undefined they are both basically $1/0$. In case anyone is unaware of how they equal $1/0$ what we can do is represent $\sec (\pi/2)$ as $\dfrac {1}{\cos (\pi/2)}$ and $\tan (\pi/2)$ as $\dfrac {\sin \pi/2}{\cos \pi/2}$ and once you put in the value they both become $\dfrac {1}{0}$.

The problem is that if $\sec (\pi/2)$ does equal $\tan (\pi/2)$ then the following should be true as well:

$\sec (\pi/2)$= $\tan (\pi/2)$

$\sec^2 (\pi/2) = \tan^2 (\pi/2)$ [By squaring both sides]

$\sec^2 (\pi/2) - \tan^2 (\pi/2)$= 0 [By subtracting $\tan^2 \pi/2$  from both sides]

$1 = 0$ [By using the formula $\sec^2 \phi - \tan^2 \phi$ = 1]

This is obviously false and from my understanding the problem is either -

(i) As I first said, maybe $\sec \pi/2 \neq \tan \pi/2$

(ii) We cannot use the formula $\sec^2 \phi - \tan^2 \phi$ for $\phi = k \pi  + \pi/2$ (where $k \in \mathbb {Z}$).

This is all from my side, I would still like to mention that I am an highschool kid and might be unaware of rules as school only teaches very limited things and I don't have an consistent method of self studying topics like trigonometry, calculus (please suggest beginner books for calculus if you can), etc. Also this was my first ever question so if there is something that could be changed in the way I am submitting the question please suggest that.

Thank you.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Undefined things can't be "equal" to each other.

Comment: You have discovered that dividing by zero is incompatible with certain rules of algebra.

Comment: "While both sec(π/2) and tan(π/2) are undefined they are both basically 1/0." - You could just make as convincing a case that they're $-1/0$. This Numberphile video covers some related issues -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRRolKTlF6Q

Comment: Whatever $1/0$ might be, it certainly is not a number. You'll get no guarantees when you try to apply arithmetic properties of numbers to things that, like $1/0$, are not numbers.

Comment: Probably consider the Laurent series of the two functions $\tan(x),\sec(x)$ at $x=\pi/2$ to see the differences.

Comment: @GEdgar OP wants us to suggest him some *beginner calculus books* ....and you're talking about *Laurent series*!!!

Comment: Thomas Finney may prove to be a good book...check if that matches your current level

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad The only thing to do there is compute the reciprocal of the Taylor series. I would not say this is any more difficult to understand

Comment: @AShrike agreed.....and are you realted to *FShrike*... Do u know them?

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad I *am* FShrike. I’m just changing my name for a few days

Comment: @oh yeah...dunno why I didn't click on your username before 

Answer (score 8):

One can make sense of the equality $\sec \frac{\pi}2=\tan\frac{\pi}2$ in terms of limits, by comparing $\sec x$ and $\tan x$ as $x$ tends to $\frac{\pi}2$.  Then $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}2}\frac{\tan x}{\sec x}=\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}2}\sin x=1$.  In this sense it can be said that $\sec x$ and $\tan x$ "tend to infinity at the same rate" when $x$ tends to $\frac{\pi}2$.  I will leave it to you as an exercise to determine whether it can be said that $\sec x$ and $\tan x$ "tend to infinity at the same rate" in the sense that $\sec x -\tan x$ tends to $0$.

As far as elementary calculus textbooks, I would recommend *Elementary Calculus* by Keisler.  The book is freely available on his homepage but that version is not searchable.  You can download a searchable version from [my page](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/88-132.html).